# HttpPostedFileBase SaveAs vs. InputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Assuming I'm just saving files to a web server.

1. What is the difference of saving an uploaded file using the SaveAs method versus processing the file via InputStream?
2. Is there a performance difference?
3. Can both accomplish large file size uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **What is the difference of saving an uploaded file using the SaveAs method versus processing the file via InputStream?**

Using `SaveAs` will just push the file to the file system. Processing using the input stream will allow you to perform any number of tasks - save to the file system, write to another stream, etc.

1. **Is there a performance difference?**

Depends on what you do. If you're comparing `SaveAs` to manually saving the file using the stream, then the difference is negligible.

1. **Can both accomplish large file size uploading?**

Yes.

Comment: I've noticed that when file is located on network share the SaveAs is sometimes fails due to credential errors, while InputStream.CopyTo is always succeeded. Any idea what is the difference? The error: "System.IO.IOException: The user name or password is incorrect."